# Map format for 3d open world

Tags: maps, ogre, file-format

I am making an open world 3d platformer in Ogre3D, and I have no idea on what kind of 3d map file format I should use for it.

I want to make low-polygon blocky-style objects. Probably rectangles and other geometrical figures that don't have circular edges. Some of those blocks will have properties, like climbable or they might move.

I was wondering what would be the best thing to do to make the map (just one level, as it is open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ogre3D, a logical choice would be to use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) for creating the map, and [Blender2Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=61485&sid=d9a6db6efe02fa15b5366c2c7ef5a374&start=650) to export the map into a .scene file.

Then, in the code, you can use the [DotSceneLoader](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/New+DotScene+Loader) class to import the .scene file into the game world. This will automatically attach each object to a scene node and you can access them as needed.